# Maintaining security with session

Tags: php

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['var'];
if($_SESSION["loginvalue"]==1)
{
echo "Welcome,$name";
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='login.php'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
```

This is code i have used to maintain session in the page. What i want is if some enter local/project/cms.php url in web browser then it should not open. I want cms.php to be open only if someone login first otherwise it should not be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $name=$_GET['var'];
    if($_SESSION["loginvalue"]==1)
    {
        echo "Welcome, ". htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='login.php'>Logout</a>";
    }else{
        //Redirect user to login page.
        header("location: /login.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Also your want to advise the OP about XSS and checking values are set before using...

Comment: @LozCherone you may want to use some CSRF middleware to get rid of CSRF and other simlar kind of attacks. I don't think session will cause any XSS issue util and unless it is exposed to the external user.

Comment: its $name thats open to XSS

Comment: @LozCherone oh! yes i did not noticed it thank you for pointing out.

Comment: what is the meaning of CSRF and XSS.It is something related to security. Please can i know what it mean..

Comment: Yes [CSRF](http://git.pentodetechnologies.com/tuyen/vxtuyen_tracking/blob/master/dashboard/models.py#L213) and [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) are related to websecurity. Check the links to know more.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you mean; but...

Firstly there are some issues with the code given, where's [session_start()](http://www.php.net/session_start), your code is also open to [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) on the `$name` var because your not escaping input, you need to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) user input **if** your going to display it back to the user. Also you need to check variables are set before using to avoid PHP undefined index  warnings. Other then that, you basically check if user is logged in, if there not then you redirect them, to your login page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $name = isset($_GET['var']) ? $_GET['var'] : null;
    if(isset($_SESSION["loginvalue"]) && $_SESSION["loginvalue"]==1)
    {
        echo "Welcome,".htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES);
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="./login.php">Logout</a>';
    }else{
        //Redirect user to login page if not logged in.
        exit(header("location: ./login.php"));
    }
?>
```